# How to show pop up box like F2 `Rename Symbol` command in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In VSCode, when we press `F2` or call command `Rename Symbol`, a pop up box is show to get the input from user. I want to show this box when user execute my command too to get the input from user. How can I archive this?
I can show a input box using `vscode.window.showInputBox` but this just show at the top of the editor. I want the box will show at current position like `Rename Symbol`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.25, you can [start a rename by invoking a command](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_rename-command). However, it sounds like that's not what you want, instead you just want to use *the same UI* as rename, but for something else? This is currently not possible, but there's an open feature reqeust for it:

[Allow to ask for input in the context of an editor (#46660)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46660)

> We have a custom UI solution for rename with the inplace-input-field.
>   [...]
>   Extensions cannot use these widgets and are stuck with `showInputBox` and the `showXYZMessage`-functions.